# SHGetKnownFolderPath Vs. reading System folder path from Registry

Tags: windows, security, known-folders

I am very new to windows system programming. In my project I need to read the registered "ProgramFiles" location for 32/64bit processes.

I have finally come up to two choices: either to use `SHGetKnownFolderPath` or to read the values for these folders from system registry, but I have some security concerns. Can someone please compare these two methods in terms of security and reliability.

Comment: http://blogs.msdn.com/b/oldnewthing/archive/2011/03/22/10144082.aspx

Answer (score 1):

You don't read stuff from undocumented random places in the registry, because that's just an implementation detail of where Windows *currently* stores that data: it may easily happen that:

- in some next version of Windows they'll decide that such data needs to be stored elsewhere;
- the data you found just is there only on some configurations (some particular IE versions installed, the machine has not joined Active Directory, there's no folder redirection inplace, ...) - but you can't know it, there's no documentation that guarantees you anything.

The correct way to go is to use the *documented* interfaces that the OS provides, on which Microsoft explicitly makes promises of compatibility (they promise that a public function that works today - if used according to the documentation - will continue to work tomorrow).

---

***tl;dr***: use `SHGetKnownFolderPath` - or `SHGetFolderPath` if you want to remain compatible with Windows versions before Vista, which in general is a good thing, given that Windows XP still seems to have more market share than all OS X versions combined.